# Read the news with R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)

feed <- "http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews?format=xml"
data <- ldply(xmlToList(feed), data.frame)
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(title = "Reuters: World News", link =
"http://www.reuters.com",  :    arguments imply differing number of
rows: 1, 3, 2
```

Why can't I load this XML (but I can load other XML such as www.w3schools.com/XQuery/books.xml)?

Comment: Did you inspect `str(xmlToList(feed))` at all? This data is not very "regular" so it's not obvious how you want to turn it into a `data.frame`.  The XML is loading just fine, but data.frame doesn't know what to do with such nested data (it prefers rectangular data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also a function `xmlToDataFrame`:

```
library(XML)
feed <- "http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews?format=xml"
(data <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse(feed)["/rss/channel/item"]))
# dplyr::glimpse(data)
# Variables:
#   $ title       (fctr) More than 60 migrants drown in boat sinking off Yemen:...
# $ link        (fctr) http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/Reuters/worldNews/~3/p08tv...
# $ description (fctr) GENEVA (Reuters) - At least 60 African migrants and tw...
# $ category    (fctr) worldNews, worldNews, worldNews, worldNews, worldNews,...
# $ pubDate     (fctr) Fri, 06 Jun 2014 19:18:12 GMT, Fri, 06 Jun 2014 19:01:...
# $ guid        (fctr) http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/06/06/us-yemen-mig...
# $ origLink    (fctr) http://reuters.us.feedsportal.com/c/35217/f/654198/s/3...
```

Comment: I actually think this answer is easier for me (a beginner) to read/understand than the other answer that I accepted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that you just want data.frames for all the "item" nodes in the result. If that's the case, then

```
feed <- "http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews?format=xml"
reuters<-xmlToList(feed)
lapply(reuters[[1]][names(reuters[[1]])=="item"], data.frame)
```

should do the trick.